# Error in run script phase: framework is a directory

Tags: swift, xcode, apollo, carthage

I'm using the apollo framework for GraphQL that I installed using Carthage but I have an error when I run the script to generate the API.swift file during the build phase.

The error is

```
> [myproject]/Carthage/Build/iOS/Apollo.framework: is a directory
  Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 126
```

I did added the script like in the [apollo doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html) :

Here is the script itself:

```
APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$(eval find $FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS -name "Apollo.framework" -maxdepth 1)"

if [ -z "$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH" ]; then
echo "error: Couldn't find Apollo.framework in FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS; make sure to add the framework to your project."
exit 1
fi

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"
$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh generate $(find . -name '*.graphql') --schema schema.json --output API.swift
```

Of course, I have also generated the schema.json beforehand

Comment: Well there is no code to show at this point, expect maybe the script itself that I just added. I followed all the steps in the doc, I just want the script to run properly and create the API.swift file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a bit late to answer but at least on my machine `APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH` gets evaluated to two frameworks (iOS and watchOS) and thus running the bundled script with `$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh` fails.

Assuming the scripts don't differ (as of version `apollo-ios@0.8.0` they don't) you can add `-print -quit` to the end of the find command to make it return only one result.

The full script will be:

```
APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$(eval find $FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS -name "Apollo.framework" -maxdepth 1 -print -quit)"

if [ -z "$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH" ]; then
echo "error: Couldn't find Apollo.framework in FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS; make sure to add the framework to your project."
exit 1
fi

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"
$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh generate $(find . -name '*.graphql') --schema schema.json --output API.swift
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. I can report that it also works for the Apollo CLI script, which Apollo is now using instead of the codegen one above.